# Which MIBs support objects for 802.11 Client Associations with Client MAC addresses?

Tags: wireless, snmp

I am trying to find the MIBs given by IETF(through RFCs) or maintained by private access point manufacturers, which support Wifi 802.11 client associations.

For example my Institute uses Airespace access points with a central controller from Cisco, and hence supports [bsnDot11StationAssociate](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.6.3.53#oidContent).

Which other enterprise MIBs from among Ericsson, Netgear, LinkSys or Cisco offer a similar object? ( giving the OID, or relevant subtrees of the MIBs)